# Correct typos from web-data request using dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

I am downloading some auto data from the web and some of the car make's may have typos. What I want to do is create a dictionary containing the possible typos as the keys and the correct spelling as the values. I am having a hard time structuring my code correctly since I am somewhat new to the requests module.

```
import requests
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


url = 'https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/auto-mpg/auto-mpg.data'
r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects = True)
open('auto-mpg.txt', 'wb').write(r.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just forgot to decode the content with `utf-8`.

The following code works for me

```py
import requests
url = "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/auto-mpg/auto-mpg.data"
res = requests.get(url,allow_redirects=True)
with open("auto-mpg.txt","w") as f:
    f.write(res.content.decode("utf-8"))
```

and the content of txt is

```
18.0   8   307.0      130.0      3504.      12.0   70  1    "chevrolet chevelle malibu"
15.0   8   350.0      165.0      3693.      11.5   70  1    "buick skylark 320"
18.0   8   318.0      150.0      3436.      11.0   70  1    "plymouth satellite"
16.0   8   304.0      150.0      3433.      12.0   70  1    "amc rebel sst"
17.0   8   302.0      140.0      3449.      10.5   70  1    "ford torino"
```